# Evaluate variables for positioning multiple times

Tags: pgfplots, nodes, coordinates

Here is a working code (I'll describe it just after) :

```
    \documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    \usepackage{graphics}
    \usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{math} % Pour evaluate
    \usetikzlibrary{calc} % Pour postionnement relatif

    \newcommand*{\addploZ}[2]{ 
        \addplot[#2,samples=60,domain=0:\Ttrace,thick=3pt,ultra thick,
            evaluate={  \Tun = (1 / ( 6 *(#1-sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ));
                    \Tdeux = (1 / ( 6 *(#1+sqrt(#1^2 -1)) )); }
            ] {  \K * (1 - ( 1/( \Tun - \Tdeux ) )*( \Tun *exp(-x/ \Tun ) - \Tdeux *exp(-x/ \Tdeux ) ))  };
    }

    \newcommand*{\LegendArrows}[5]{ 
        \pgfmathparse{(1 / ( 6 *(#1-sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ))} \pgfmathresult \let\Tun\pgfmathresult
        \pgfmathparse{(1 / ( 6 *(#1+sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ))} \pgfmathresult \let\Tdeux\pgfmathresult
        \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, {  \K * (1 - ( 1/( \Tun - \Tdeux ) )*( \Tun *exp(-#2/ \Tun ) 
                - \Tdeux *exp(-#2/ \Tdeux ) ))  }) ;
        \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#2$};
        \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
    }       

    \tikzset{ fleche/.style={<-,>=latex,line width=0.2mm,shorten <=-0.02cm} }

    \begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \def\K{2}
    \def\w{(3.14159*2)}
    \def\Ttrace{3}

    \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, axis y line = left, width=13cm, height=\axisdefaultheight,ymax=1.55*\K,
    ytick=\empty,extra y ticks={\K}, extra y tick labels={},extra y tick style={grid=major}
    ]

    \addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),thick=1pt] { \K };

    \addploZ{2}{blue}
    \addploZ{4}{red}

    \LegendArrows{4}{0.6}{west}{C3}{($(C2)+(axis cs:1,-0.5)$)}
    \LegendArrows{2}{0.6}{south}{C4}{(C3.north)}

    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}


    \end{document}
```

It compiles to give you this masterpiece:
[image: conjoint arrows on plot]
But you can see the problem, the arrows point to the same point.

Look at the body,
Lets break it down :

```
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
```

a few variables for my functions :

```
    \def\K{2}
    \def\w{(3.14159*2)}
    \def\Ttrace{3}
```

some plot properties

```
    \begin{axis}[axis x line=bottom, axis y line = left, width=13cm, height=\axisdefaultheight,ymax=1.55*\K,
    ytick=\empty,extra y ticks={\K}, extra y tick labels={},extra y tick style={grid=major}
    ]
```

an horizontal asymptot

```
    \addplot[samples=2,domain=0:(\Ttrace+0.1),thick=1pt] { \K };
```

Now calling a function created above:

```
    \addploZ{2}{blue}
    \addploZ{4}{red}
```

It's calling this one :

```
\newcommand*{\addploZ}[2]{ 
    \addplot[#2,samples=60,domain=0:\Ttrace,thick=3pt,ultra thick,
        evaluate={  \Tun = (1 / ( 6 *(#1-sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ));
                \Tdeux = (1 / ( 6 *(#1+sqrt(#1^2 -1)) )); }
        ] {  \K * (1 - ( 1/( \Tun - \Tdeux ) )*( \Tun *exp(-x/ \Tun ) - \Tdeux *exp(-x/ \Tdeux ) ))  };
}
```

You can see I am using `evaluate` to find the value of two parameters :`\Tun` et `\Tdeux` based on the first parameter (I call it z if you want to know) sent to newcommand. So z=2 in the first call and z=4 in the second one.

And since you can see the two curves, `evaluate` does it work and I get what I want.

**The troubles comes after:**

Using arrow to point at the curves:

```
    \LegendArrows{4}{0.6}{west}{C3}{($(C2)+(axis cs:1,-0.5)$)}
    \LegendArrows{2}{0.6}{south}{C4}{(C3.north)}
```

Calling the function :

```
\newcommand*{\LegendArrows}[5]{ 
    \pgfmathparse{(1 / ( 6 *(#1-sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ))} \pgfmathresult \let\Tun\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{(1 / ( 6 *(#1+sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ))} \pgfmathresult \let\Tdeux\pgfmathresult
    \coordinate (C2) at (axis cs:#2, {  \K * (1 - ( 1/( \Tun - \Tdeux ) )*( \Tun *exp(-#2/ \Tun ) 
            - \Tdeux *exp(-#2/ \Tdeux ) ))  }) ;
    \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#2$};
    \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
}
```

This gives me colliding arrows because of the evaluation of `\Tun` and `\Tdeux` placing the node I called `C2`. I suppose the two evaluations using `\pgfmathparse` for the two callings of the function are done before the arrows are plotted, and therefore `C2` is placed for both arrows at the same spot (the one of the last evaluation).

You can correct me if I'm wrong.

Anyway I tried other solutions, my first try was to duplicate the code I used to plot the function because I need to evaluate the same quantities, like so:

```
    \newcommand*{\LegendArrows}[5]{ 
        \coordinate[evaluate={  \Tun = (1 / ( 6 *(#1-sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ));
                    \Tdeux = (1 / ( 6 *(#1+sqrt(#1^2 -1)) )); }
            ] (C2) at (axis cs:#2, {  \K * (1 - ( 1/( \Tun - \Tdeux ) )*( \Tun *exp(-#2/ \Tun ) - \Tdeux *exp(-#2/ \Tdeux ) ))  }) ;
        \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#2$};
        \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
    }
```

but as I got a compilation error I suppose `evaluate` is an option of `\addplot` but not of `\coordinate`. However it is a option of `\node` so I can try :

```
    \newcommand*{\LegendArrows}[5]{ 
        \node[evaluate={  \Tun = (1 / ( 6 *(#1-sqrt(#1^2 -1)) ));
                    \Tdeux = (1 / ( 6 *(#1+sqrt(#1^2 -1)) )); }
            ] (C2) at (axis cs:#2, {  \K * (1 - ( 1/( \Tun - \Tdeux ) )*( \Tun *exp(-#2/ \Tun ) - \Tdeux *exp(-#2/ \Tdeux ) ))  }) {} ;
        \draw node[anchor=#3] (#4) at #5 {$z =#2$};
        \draw[fleche] (C2) -- (#4.west) ;
    }
```

which gives :
[image: separated arrow but gap at the end]

You can see here the arrows are separated like I want, but the use of `node` created that gap between the arrows and the curve which is why I tried to use `\coordinate` in the first place

And to be thoroughn here comes the end of the body:

```
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

So to sum up my request, I ask for your help either:

- to help me with the correct evaluation using `\coordinate`
- to correct that gap created whenever I use an empty `\node` as an anchor.
- to come up with improvement and clever tricks like this community so often do

Thank you in advance

Comment: With nodes: `(C2.center) -- (#4.west)`.

Comment: I thought I had tried the center anchor without success, but this time it works fine so thank you.

Comment: `\node [coordinate, evaluate=..] or `\path[evaluate=...] coordinate...` works. Don't know why it doesn't work with `\coordinate` directly.